# Listen to key press Enter in Quill.js

Tags: javascript, quill

According to the documentation, Quill can handle the Enter key but I can't make it work.

I have followed these steps listed on their site:

1. Import Keyboard module: `const Keyboard = Quill.import('modules/keyboard');` [Quill.js Extension import documentation.](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#import)
2. Add the custom event called key binding. [Quill.js Key binding documentation](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/)
3. Call a function to handle the event.

My code is the following:

`quill.keyboard.addBinding({`
`key: Keyboard.keys.ENTER,`
`handler: function(range, context) {`
`console.log('Enter Key!!!');`
`result.innerText = 'Key presset = ENTER';`
`}`
`})`

[Code example](https://jsfiddle.net/el_alien/92jxL8aa/5/)

I have tried on Chrome (latest version) and Safari 11.0.3 on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to prevent future bubbling of the enter key. You have to put your handler first, then return `true` if you want to continue bubbling.

```
quillEditor.keyboard.bindings[13].unshift({
        key: 13,
        handler: (range, context) => {
            if (this.popupVisible) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you want the Enter key or the Space key but you were on the right page with the [Keyboard module](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/) but missed this key sentence:

> The `key` is the JavaScript event key code, but string shorthands are allowed for alphanumeric keys and some common keys.

So you can either specify 13 or 'enter' if you meant the Enter key or 32 if you meant the Space key (sadly there is no shortcut for the Space key).

The upcoming 2.0 version (no public timeline) will also support the new easier to use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) but currently you should use [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

Comment: Hi jochen, thanks for the quick answer. Effectively I want the Enter key. En in the post I copied the wrong event listener, but in the JS fiddle link is the entire script.

Comment: Hi, I tried with key: 13 and key: 'enter' but not luck. A copy of the sample code with the updated listeners is here [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/el_alien/qqjekxch/)

Comment: Right also on the Keyboard docs page: "Note: Since Quill’s default handlers are added at initialization, the only way to prevent them is to add yours in the configuration." So you would have to do that instead of using addBinding. Quill does this on a number of key events to normalize browser behavior and fix bugs so this is is changing with browser releases.

Comment: Thank you for your follow up, I will try the solution you proposed and come back with the results.

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Comment: To disable the key Enter (keycode 13) :
`configToolbar.keyboard.bindings.handleEnter = {
     key: 13,
     handler: () => {
      return false;
     }
    };`