# Couldn't get the quilljs editor ENTER key press event listener in angular 4+

Tags: angular, quill

I read about addbinding [from official quilljs dicumentation here](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/) but i couldn't get ENTER key press event listener, tried other keys and BACKSPACE and they are working as expected but ENTER key event listener is not working.
I was following related post [here in so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775485/listen-to-key-press-enter-in-quill-js) but not able to understand,
can anyone please provide an example or explain a little on how to add event listener for enter key in configuration?

what i tried so far,

```
quill.keyboard.addBinding({
  key: Keyboard.keys.ENTER,
}, function(range, context) {
  console.log("enter clicked");
});
```

--

```
quill.keyboard.addBinding({
  key: 13,
}, function(range, context) {
  console.log("enter clicked");
});
```

--

```
quill.keyboard.addBinding({
  key: 'enter',
}, function(range, context) {
  console.log("enter clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I figured out your problem. For special keys like enter and tab you have to overwrite the standard quill documentation. I did so as such:

```js
bindings = {
    enter: {
      key: 13,
      handler: function() {
        console.log('enter pressed');
        this.hideSymbols = !this.hideSymbols;
        console.log(this.hideSymbols);
      }
    }
  };
```

```js
this.modules = {
      keyboard: {
        bindings: this.bindings
      },
      formula: true,
      toolbar: true,
      counter: { container: '#counter', unit: 'word' },
      equalsSymbol: { container: '#equalsBtn', selector: 'equals' },
      impliesSymbol: { container: '#impliesBtn', selector: 'implies' }
    };
```

So essentially just make your own bindings object and in your modules call in your constructor add your custom bindings to keyboard as I did.

Comment: Hi @Frank, i'm struggling to understand this, can you please provide an example or an explanation on how to implement this logic

Comment: this is an implementation using Angular so its probably a little different if you are using the standard vanilla javascript library but the idea is still the same. (https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/) Check out this link and scroll to the "Configuration" section, this outlines how to overwrite a default quill bindings and add your custom key to the configuration.